# Undefined String in the last character of SerialPort ReadLine VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, barcode

I make program using vb.net where it connected to barcode scanner using rs232 connection. As generally, I use serialport communication (SerialPort1.ReadLine) to get data from barcode scanner. First I think it's work because the barcode value appears in the textbox until I get it can't show the data which has relation with barcode value.

The barcode value is same with data in database, but it can't show. So I try to copy the data from textbox then found that there are the undefined string in the last character of textbox. It's like space but not, when I copy that textbox value to the winword, the value enter automatically, so, i just want to know how my programs can read the barcode value without that undefined string.

Thank you,

Comment: Hard to decode, but it is probably a control character like a carriage return (ASCII code 13).  Change the SerialPort.NewLine property, start by assigning it with Environment.NewLine

Comment: well, how to do that?

Comment: `SerialPort1.NewLine = Environment.NewLine`  Probably best if you try to find help at a forum where you can get answers in your native language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have another solution and I think it's better solution then using NewLine property.

Actually the character in the last string of barcode value is vbCr or vbLf, I don't know what that's mean, but I know it in the manual of barcode scanner. So to remove that character we can use mid function and replace that character with this string "".

Answer (score 0):

When a bar code scanner is configured often the default is to add a termination string called a suffix or a postamble. The termination string is useful to tell the receiving program that all of the data has been sent.

It can be set to anything; a common configuration I’ve seen is the carriage return (`vbCr`) linefeed (`vbLf`) pair. You could also set it to not send anything additional which is also a common configuration.

You can build in a configuration option in your VB code to specify a termination string. Your program would  look for this termination string as you are receiving the data from the serial port and then strip it out before sending it to the next part of your program. This allows you to easily handle various scanner brands and configurations by changing your configured string.

It is possible for serial data to be delayed and not receive everything at once. By checking for the termination string you can be sure you received it all before acting on it. If you have data but do not see your terminator save the received string and add the additional data as it arrives.

Bar code scanners also have a suffix or prefix that is prepended to the beginning of a scan. This can be used to identify the bar code symbology or other useful information.  Usually the default I’ve seen is not to send anything.